# Model factory Zend 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like an elegant way of creating a factory of models (TableGateway) by using Zend Framework 2.

I would not like to put all the dependency injection in file module.config.php.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you ask something, it is always a good idea to provide some code of things you have done so far. In this example, provide the code that you find not to be working out for you (for whatever reason) and ask for alternatives. A two-liner isn't really fit for Q&A all too much. My answer is based on the assumption of what you wanna do (which i'm not all too sure about)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't like that either and for a better readability i put it all into factory classes.

**Module.php**

```
class Module implements \Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'namespace-model-servicename' => 'Namespace\Factory\SomemodelServiceFactory'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**Namespace\Factory\Servicename.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Namespace\Model\SomemodelService;

class SomemodelServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return \Namespace\Service\SomemodelService
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $service = new SomemodelService();
        $service->setEntityManager($serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));
        return $service;
    }
}
```

This now is an example of a ServiceFactory that injects Doctrines EntityManager. Obviously you'd need to refactor all classes and stuff to fit your needs, but basically this is the approach you'd be running.